# Special Characters SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a pre-populated Android SQLite database which has some fields that contain text with special characters, like accented letters, or characters like ü, ecc.
When I retrieve the data and display the text, it's like this:

[image]

To show the text I'm using a TextView, and normally setting the text with the query result:

```
prep.setText(recipePrep);
```

How can I display the data correctly?

Comment: The database does not change strings. The values are not encoded correctly when written or read by your code.

Comment: How Can I encode the values correctly?

Comment: By removing the bugs from the code that writes the strings.

Comment: I'm not editing the db. it's already populated, i'm only retrieving data.

Comment: How did you populate it?

Comment: I imported the data from a .CSV file

Comment: How? And what is the encoding of the CSV file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139500/discussion-between-cosimo-sguanci-and-cl).